# TailwindCSS not working on Next.js 13 (with app folder)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, package.json, app-folder

I've installed the latest version of of tailwindcss, but when I run the command "npm run dev", tailwind does not change anything but the fonts.

1. My tailwind.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

2. The postcss.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

3. package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "next-authex1dot1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "animal-avatar-generator": "^1.1.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "eslint": "8.37.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.2.4",
    "http-errors": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mongoose": "^7.0.3",
    "next": "13.2.4",
    "next-auth": "^4.20.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "swr": "^2.1.2",
    "validator": "^13.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "concurrently": "^8.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```

4. ./app/globals.css file:

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

5. layout.js file:

```
"use client"

import "./globals.css";
import  NavBar  from "./components/navbar/NavBar";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";


export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <SessionProvider>
          <NavBar />
          {children}
        </SessionProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

then, in ./app/page.jsx (which is my homepage):

```
export default function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <h1 className="text-2xl underline">
      Hello world!
    </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It only changes the font, but does not do what it's supposed to do in h1 className, as seen in ss below:
[image: Homepage]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives)

> Use the @tailwind directive to insert Tailwind’s base, components,
> utilities and variants styles into your CSS.

in `globals.css`, you should have

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside tailwind.config.js, add paths to the files that will use Tailwind CSS class names:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}', // Note the addition of the `app` directory.
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
 
    // Or if using `src` directory:
    './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

from [Nextjs 13 - Tailwind](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling/tailwind-css)